# I have a problem using pydub library in python, Even I have read its documentation and I have downloaded it in my windows mahcine

Tags: python, audio

[image: This is my code on pychram that I have used in my project]

[image: And this is the error that I got after running the project]

I also have tried to run the project on my linux machine (distribution: Kali Linux) and I have imported the pydub, but it says module not found even after I have downloaded it

Comment: So you installed ffmpeg and still got that error? How did you install ffmpeg? ffmpeg is its own external program that has to be downloaded and installed separately, I'm pretty sure

Comment: I have followed this link to download it: https://www.wikihow.com/Install-FFmpeg-on-Windows. with no result

Comment: If you type `ffmpeg` in the Windows Command Prompt does it work? If not then you installed it wrong. And therefore this issue is a computer software installation issue and has nothing to do with code or StackOverflow.